# 2D Probability Density Map with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a 2D probability density map diagrammatic sketch using tikz.

[image: image link]

However, I can not find similar example online. Is it possible to draw similar figures using tikz? Thanks!

Comment: have a look at pgfplots package

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `pgfplots` package to easily produce such plots in tikz:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[view={0}{90}]
    \addplot3 [surf] {exp(-sqrt(x^2 + y^2))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]